# Git command line for combining commits

Tags: git, tortoisegit

In Tortoisegit you can select multiple commits at the head of a branch and replace them with a single commit. (`Show the log`, `select the commits`, `and right click`). When this happens, you are given the opportunity to write a new commit message.

What is the command line equivalent to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do an interactive rebase.

`git rebase -i master`

will rebase your current branch on master and let you edit/remove/rearrange commits and edit commit messages.  You can also arbitrarily select which branch or range of commits to rebase and onto which branch.

[Interactive rebase help on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/interactive-rebase)

[Git rebase docs](ftp://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html)